# How to format date string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reformat the string date to date as mentioned below:

```
'25th May 1912' → 1912-05-2
```

I tried with Date.parse() but it throws an error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need the solution to work only for the 25th, or for other dates like the 21st, 22nd, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `th` from your date, `Date.parse` returns `NaN` because of it.
This should work:

```
var input = '25th May 1912';
var validInput = input.replace(/(th|st|nd|rd)/, '');
var dateObj = new Date(Date.parse(validInput))
console.log(dateObj.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (dateObj.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + dateObj.getDate()).slice(-2));
```

Comment: That's not going to work for the 21st, 22nd, etc.

Comment: @brabster Now it will. I just left that on the person asking question. but anyway, thanks :)

Comment: I have tried it without using the parse, but I like this approach.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript's [built-in date parsing is very limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), it doesn't support many formats.

As suggested by the documentation linked above, I would use a library to parse this format, such as [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/), unless there was a reason not to (page load times, etc.).

I think the following will parse and reformat it:

`moment("25th May 1912", "Do MMM YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD");`

It'll also parse variations like "21st May 1912" that might cause bugs in simple hand-rolled implementations.

Using a library helps avoid bugs you might not have thought of and avoids growing nasty, hard to read string hacking code in your application.

Comment: You may want to add the full parsing and formatting example: `moment('25th May 1912', 'Do MMM YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-D');`

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log( parse('25st May 1912') )
console.log( parse('2nd September 2018') )
console.log( parse('6th January 2015') )

function parse(str) {
  let replaced = str.replace(/(th|st|nd|rd)/, '')
  let date = new Date(Date.parse(replaced))
  
  return date.toISOString().slice(0, 10)
}
```

Comment: That's not going to work for the 21st, 22nd, etc.

Comment: I like it, clean and elegant

Comment: Your regular expression is wrong - it's one big character set. You should probably alternate instead, and no need for it to be global.

Comment: Relying on the built–in parser is never a good idea. What should `parse('29th February 2019')` return? See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)